# recursive module as a fix point in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml

Is it possible to write the module `Nat` as a fixpoint or a universal algebra for some functor `NatF` ?

```ml
module rec Nat : sig
  type t = Z | S of Nat.t
end = struct
  type t = Z | S of Nat.t
end
```

Presumably `to_int` would then be a regular fold

```ml
let rec to_int : Nat.t -> int = function Z -> 0 | S x -> 1 + to_int x
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Is there anything wrong with the proposed definition? Also a fixed point of what relation? Inductive data types already define a fixed point. And what do you mean by the universal algebra for some functor?

Comment: This definition works, and it defines a fixed point implicitly. I wonder if the operation of taking the fixed point can be make explicit in the OCaml language itself, and applied to a relation also explicitly defined.

Comment: in categorical jargon, that's equivalent to an "algebra" (NatF (Nat) -> Nat) of "carrier" Nat, and where NatF is a categorical functor (presumably from a category "Module" - whose object are modules and morphisms are ... to be defined - to itsef), which is "initial" in the sense that any algebra (NatF M -> M) of carrier any M has a unique "algebra morphism" (Nat -> M) from it

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I fully understand your question, but it looks like that you want to define a fixed-point combinator on the type level, so that you can write,

```
  module NatF = Fix(functor (F : F)(T:T) -> struct
      type t = Z | S of F(T).t
    end)
  module R = NatF(struct type s type t = Z | S of s end)
```

It is possible, e.g.,

```
  module type T = sig type t end
  module type F = functor (T : T) -> T
  module type F2F = functor (F : F) -> F
  module type Fix = functor (F : F2F) -> F
  module rec Fix : Fix = functor (F : F2F) -> F (Fix(F))
```

but the problem is that it will leave the resulting type `R.t` abstract, so you can't write the `to_int` function over `R.t`. Even if you will try to define the `to_int` function inside of the open-recursive functor, you won't be able to recurse over the `F(T).t` type of the `S` branch as it will be abstract.

So, I believe, that in the end, you will still have to rely either on the recursion that is implicit in the type definition or on recursive modules to tighten up the fixed point, e.g.,

```
  module type T = sig type t end
  module Nat (T : T) = struct
    module type S = sig
      type t = Z | S of T.t
    end
  end
  module type F = functor (T : T) -> Nat(T).S

  module type F2F = functor (F : F) -> F
  module type Fix = functor (F : F2F) -> F

  module rec Fix : Fix = functor (F : F2F) -> F (Fix(F))

  module F = functor(F : F)(T : T) -> struct
    type t = F(T).t = Z | S of T.t
  end

  module rec R : sig
    type t = Z | S of R.t
  end = Fix(F)(R)
```

Answer (score 0):

rephrasing Ivg's answer and its issue (with a tweak to make it compile - interesting to understand "safe module")

```ml
module Ivg = struct
  module type T = sig type t end
  module type F = functor (T : T) -> T

  module NatF (T : T) = struct
    type t = Z | S of T.t
  end

  module type Fix = functor (F : F) -> T
  module rec Fix : Fix =
  functor (F : F) -> F (struct type t = Fix(F).t end) (*tweak - prevent loop at definition - cf "safe module" at https://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/xleroy-recursive_modules-03.pdf *)

  module Nat = Fix (NatF)

  (* As mentioned by @ivg : 
     it will leave the resulting type Nat.t abstract,
     so you can't write the to_int function over Nat.t.
     Even if you will try to define the to_int function inside of the open-recursive functor,
     you won't be able to recurse over the F(T).t type of the S branch as it will be abstract. *)
end
```

Whose solution can be approximated by

```ml
  module type T = sig type t  end
  module type F = functor (T : T) -> T

  module rec NatF : F =
  functor (T : T) ->
    struct
      type t = Z | S of T.t
    end

  and FixedNat : T = struct
    type t = NatF(FixedNat).t
  end
```

Fix now statically know it is being applied to NatF.
But `T` is still abstract

I don't know any other way as of yet (modular implicit ?)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of expressing `Nat`

```ml
(* type 't natF = Z | S of 't *)
module rec FixedNat : sig
  module type Z = sig end

  module type S = sig
    val n : FixedNat.n
  end

  type n = Z | S of (module S)
end =
  FixedNat

let rec to_int : FixedNat.n -> int = function
  | Z -> 0
  | S (module N) -> to_int N.n
```

which still does not express `FixedNat` as an explicit fix point of an algebra

Answer (score 0):

Another approximate solution.

The encoding of modules fixed point can be done through its universal property for type level algebras

```ml
  module Algebras = struct
    (* type level natf_algebra :  'a natF -> 'a  *)
    module type natF_algebra = sig
      type a

      val zero : a
      val succ : a -> a
    end

    (* A type level algebra lowered *)
    type 'a natF_algebra = (module natF_algebra with type a = 'a)

    (* is an ordinary value level algebra *)
    type 'a natf = Z | S of 'a
    type 'a natf_algebra = { alg : 'a natf -> 'a }
  end

  module Encoding = struct
    open Algebras

    (* Universal encoding *)
    module type NatU = sig
      module Ap : functor (F : natF_algebra) -> sig
        val res : F.a
      end
    end

    type natU = (module NatU)

    (* recursive module *)
    module rec FixedNat : sig
      module type Z = sig end

      module type S = sig
        val n : FixedNat.n
      end

      type n = Z | S of (module S)
    end =
      FixedNat
  end

  module Equivalence = struct
    open Algebras
    open Encoding

    let fixedNat_to_natU : FixedNat.n -> natU =
     fun n ->
      (module struct
        module Ap (F : natF_algebra) = struct
          let rec foldNat = function
            | FixedNat.Z -> F.zero
            | FixedNat.S (module N) -> foldNat N.n |> F.succ

          let res = foldNat n
        end
      end)

    let rec natU_to_fixedNat : natU -> FixedNat.n =
     fun (module N) ->
      let module M = N.Ap (struct
        type a = FixedNat.n

        let zero = FixedNat.Z

        let succ x =
          FixedNat.S
            (module struct
              let n = x
            end)
      end) in
      M.res
  end
```